# decouple process remotely launched from local machine

Tags: bash, process, ssh, terminal

I need to ssh to a machine and launch a bash script running some hour-long tests which require no human interaction for their entire execution.

Is there any way I can decouple my running script from my shell, so that I can close the terminal and shut down my local computer as I like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use `nohup`:

```
nohup ./program &
```

Alternatively, start your program inside `screen` or `tmux` and then detach.

Comment: Thanks! I guess `nohup` is the easiest solution.